# Which sort algorithm is this?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I tried this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < vec.size(); j++) {
        if (vec[i] > vec[j]) {
                
            T temp = vec[j];
            vec[j] = vec[i];
            vec[i] = temp;
            n++;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if this should be called bubble sort or not?

I tested it multiple times, and it works.